# Launch my own program in console mode with Linux

Tags: python, linux, console, raspberry-pi

I wrote a tiny console program in C# for test purpose. It's just an advanced "Hello world", really. Now I need to run it on a RaspberryPi. It's very light (just two imbricated loops, and a json reading method).

The thing is I've never developed on Linux so I don't really know where to start. I'm thinking about using Python. I found Urwid (http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html), and I guess it could do the job, but I wanted to get some advices.

So:

- Which language should I use?
- Do I have to use a specific interface such as Urwid ?

By advance, thank you.

Comment: What are you really asking? How to run a python program in the terminal?

Comment: Not really, I can easily find the solution on google for that.

My question was more: which language should I use, and do I have to use an interface such as Urwid?

Comment: Original message edited.

Comment: Raspbian (RPi operating system) is a linux distribution just like Ubuntu, as such you can just use a regular terminal. You don't need anything special.

Comment: As for the language, python is heavily supported on RPi, but you can use C or perl or... it really doesn't matter unless you are thinking about doing something really specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need urwid to print a simple "Hello World!" text in python. (I've seen and it has some cool functionnalities.) And yes, python is a great choice for a raspberry pi, it's lightweight and quite efficient. Although if you want to create a larger program, I would recomend you to develop it in C — even if it is a more advanced language.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, my program is a quizz that have to catch user inputs!